# Showing a accessory checkmark view move the table View with Content

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Hi I am using **custom Table** to display content in table view and while **selecting** and **deselection**, i am also using **accessory check**

But when I select any row using accessory check, The View elements in custom table Gets move towards Left side.

My Custom Table Cell Look like this.

[image]

After Selection Table View Look Like this

[image]

I check The [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16510999/2522603) question but it s not working well.

My Code for **cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 PackageTableCell *cell = (PackageTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:packageCell];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[PackageTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:packageCell];
}
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

JobAndPackDetails *obj =[self.arrayOfJobList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell.lblJobName setText:obj.jobName];
[cell.lblJobDescription setText:obj.jobDesc];
[cell.lblJobType setText:obj.jobType];
[cell.lblJobSK setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f",obj.jobSK]];
[cell.imgVehicle setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];



cell.OuterVIEW .autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
[cell.contentView addSubview:cell.OuterVIEW];

if ([obj.jobType isEqualToString:@"JPK"]){
    [cell.imgJPK setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"vs_package.png"]];
}else{
    [cell.imgJPK setImage:nil];
}

if ([array_SelectedRows containsObject:indexPath] || (([[self.arrayJob_Package valueForKey:@"JobTypeSK"] containsObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f",obj.jobSK]]&& [[self.arrayJob_Package valueForKey:@"JobType"] containsObject:obj.jobType])&&self.isCalledFromBookAppointment))
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark ;
}
else
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone ;
}
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Are they moved, or is the white view resized?

Comment: @Avi white Outer-view get resized.

Comment: @Avi have u checked my issue

Comment: You must have constraints set to shrink `OuterVIEW` when the cell's accessory view is visible.  This doesn't appear to be a problem in and of its self.  You probably just want to set background colors so it's not obvious.

Comment: @Avi sorry could not get u. could u update an answer briefly

Comment: The reason that your `OuterVIEW` shrinks is because of the constraints.  I can't see what constraints you have, so I can't tell which one.